# WSO2 Micro Integrator 1.2.0 call data service over local transport

Tags: wso2

I have a Proxy Service which calls Data Service. I want to call Data Service over local transport but I got an error:

```
[2020-12-19 23:48:59,567] ERROR {ClientUtils} - The system cannot infer the transport information from the local:///services/test/ URL.
[2020-12-19 23:48:59,567] ERROR {Axis2Sender} - {proxy:TST2} Unexpected error during sending message out org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system cannot infer the transport information from the local:///services/test/ URL.
        at org.apache.axis2.description.ClientUtils.inferOutTransport(ClientUtils.java:86)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.DynamicAxisOperation$DynamicOperationClient.executeImpl(DynamicAxisOperation.java:116)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.send(Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.java:656)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:86)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:573)
        at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.send(AbstractEndpoint.java:409)
        at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AddressEndpoint.send(AddressEndpoint.java:74)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:123)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:109)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:226)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:458)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:181)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

My Sequence is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="TST2" startOnLoad="true" transports="http https" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                <format>
                    <soapenv:Envelope
                        xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                        xmlns:test="test-ns">
                        <soapenv:Header />
                        <soapenv:Body>
                            <test:_get_test_getcnt />
                        </soapenv:Body>
                    </soapenv:Envelope>
                </format>
            </payloadFactory>
            <header name="soapAction" scope="transport" value="urn:_get_test_getcnt"></header>
            <send>
                <endpoint>
                    <address uri="local:///services/test/" format="soap11"/>
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <log level="full" />
            <respond />
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence>
            <log level="full" />
        </faultSequence>
    </target>
    <publishWSDL key="wsdl"></publishWSDL>
</proxy>
```

Data serivce have allowed local transport:

```
<data transports="http local https" serviceNamespace="test-ns" name="test">
```

If I change the endpoint address uri to HTTP transport http://localhost:8290/services/test/ everything works fine.
Am I doing something wrong or local transport is not supported in WSO2 Micro Integrator 1.2.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is different for each version of the Enterprise Integrator.

## For version 6.x.x

You can use this manual: https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Local+Transport

## For version 7.x.x

Unfortunately version 7.x.x is very poorly documented in many parts including this one.

### Solution

Add the following section to your **conf/deployment.toml**

```
[transport.local.sender.nonblocking]
enable = true
```

#### Note

In the older solutions it was also necessary to replace ServerURL property for

```xml
<ServerURL>https://${carbon.local.ip}:${carbon.management.port}${carbon.context}/services/</ServerURL>
```

However, my EI´s local transport worked even without this change

### Why does it work

As in the previous version, what is needed to be done is add the following row manually to **conf/axis2/axis2.xml**

```xml
<transportSender name="local" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.local.NonBlockingLocalTransportSender"/>
```

Unfortunately, that won´t work as your file will get replaced with a new one without your changes in it once the enterprise integrator starts.
Your axis2.xml is being replaced by a generated jinja2 template from location **repository/resources/conf/templates/conf/axis2/axis2.xml.j2**

You can notice that there is this piece of code inside:

```
{% if transport.local.sender.nonblocking.enable == true %}
    <transportSender name="local" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.local.NonBlockingLocalTransportSender"/>
{% endif %}
```

Which means all you need to do is to add property **transport.local.sender.nonblocking.enable** and set it to true

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable the local transport in MI as mentioned in [1].

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Local+Transport